# C# - HttpClient doesn't resolve hostname, however Dns.GetHostEntry() does

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient

I'm facing a strange behaviour of my `HttpClient` instance.
I'm using it to check if a local network server is reachable or not.

When I call `Dns.GetHostEntry()` the hostname gets resolved and returns two IP addresses.

```
//_server.ServerAddress = http://myserver.local:3344
IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry(_server.ServerAddress);
if(host != null)
{
    Result += $"Host entry found for address {_server.FullWebAddress}:\n";
    foreach (IPAddress foundHost in host.AddressList)
    {
        Result += $"IP: {foundHost}\n";
    }
}
```

Result:

```
Host entry found for address http://myserver.local:3344:
IP: fe80::ba27:...
IP: 192.168.x.x
```

Afterwards I do the online check with the same hostname (`_server.ServerAddress`).

```
static HttpClient client = new();

string uriString = _server.FullWebAddress;
try
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(uriString, cts.Token).ConfigureAwait(false);
    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    if (response != null)
    {
        isReachable = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;
    }
}
catch (InvalidOperationException iexc)
{
    OnError(new UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(iexc, false));
}
catch (HttpRequestException rexc)
{
    OnError(new UnhandledExceptionEventArgs(rexc, false));
}
catch (TaskCanceledException)
{
    // Throws an exception on timeout, not actually an error
}
```

However this one fails with `Exception`

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt. (myserver.local:3344)
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (11001): Der angegebene Host ist unbekannt.
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.ThrowException(SocketError error, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.<ConnectAsync>g__WaitForConnectWithCancellation|283_0(AwaitableSocketAsyncEventArgs saea, ValueTask connectTask, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.DefaultConnectAsync(SocketsHttpConnectionContext context, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(Func`3 callback, DnsEndPoint endPoint, HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.ConnectAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.CreateHttp11ConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.GetHttpConnectionAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.SendAsyncCore(HttpRequestMessage request, HttpCompletionOption completionOption, Boolean async, Boolean emitTelemetryStartStop, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

Is there any setting I miss for the `HttpClient`?
Thanks for helping out!

Comment: Does `_server.FullWebAddress` contain the port as well? Have you tried telnetting to the Uri to ensure connections are possible? Just because the host address exists doesn't mean there is something listening for connection there.

Comment: Yes, the port is included in the uri string. http://myserver.local:3344/ 
I actually just want to see if the url is reachable or not. This seemed to be the best way, till this problem came up.